# How do I find the orthogonal projection of a vector onto an arbitrary plane?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, plane-geometry

We have a plane $H$ described by the equation $\theta_0 + \theta \cdot x = 0 $, where $\theta_0$ is the offset (a scalar) and $\theta_= [\theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_3]^T$ is an orthogonal vector, not necessarily of unit length.

What is the formula for the orthogonal projection of an arbitrary vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$ onto this plane? How do we derive it?

In other words, I'm looking for an expression for the vector in $H$ that represents the orthogonal projection of an arbitrary vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$ onto $H$, in terms of $v$, $\theta$, $\theta_0$, and their dot products only.

Answer (score 1):

Compute the intersection of the plane and the perpendicular line through $v$. One way to do this is to substitute $v+t\theta$ into the equation of the plane and solve for $t$. If you’re familiar with homogeneous coordinates, you can instead use the [Plücker matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pl%C3%BCcker_matrix) of this line to compute the intersection point directly.

Comment: I would suggest using definition orthographic parallel projection in Table 1, page 9 of [Unified Framework of Elementary Geometric Transformation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.0998)

Comment: @user106688 Make that an answer of your own instead of commenting on a completely different method.

Comment: The thus obtained homogeneous matrix of the projection requires homogenous coordiante, $$\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
 {\theta_2}^2+{\theta_3}^2 & -{\theta_1} {\theta_2} & -{\theta_1}
   {\theta_3} & -{\theta_0} {\theta_1} \\
 -{\theta_1} {\theta_2} & {\theta_1}^2+{\theta_3}^2 & -{\theta_2}
   {\theta_3} & -{\theta_0} {\theta_2} \\
 -{\theta_1} {\theta_3} & -{\theta_2} {\theta_3} & {\theta
   1}^2+{\theta_2}^2 & -{\theta_0} {\theta_3} \\
\end{array}
\right]$$ that is what the OP has to learn

Comment: the question has been closed for answers @amd

Comment: @user106688 Meh. If one is going to use homogeneous coordinates, using the Plücker matrix—without constructing it explicitly—is much easier and cheaper to compute.

Comment: Well, then you’re too late, aren’t you? The OP is never going to see comments on an answer. At the very least, comment on the _question_, if you must.

Comment: you are right. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Normalize $\theta$  and consequently $\theta_0$ to read:

$${\bf n} \cdot {\bf x} = d$$
that means that the plane is at distance $d$ from the origin, measured along ${\bf n}$.

Then $d' = \vec{OP} \cdot {\bf n} - d$ is the (signed) distance of the point P from the plane.
And once you have the distance, then $\vec{OP}-d' {\bf n}$ is the projection of P onto the plane.

Now that you got the "visualization" of the process you can arrange the steps and simplify.