# How to find the orthogonal projection of a vector onto an arbitrary plane?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, plane-geometry

We have an arbitrary plane $H$ (not necessarily a linear subspace) described by the equation $\theta_0 + \theta \cdot x = 0 $, where $\theta_0$ is the offset parameter (a scalar) and $\theta_= [\theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_3]^T$ is an orthogonal vector, not necessarily of unit length.

What is the formula for the orthogonal projection of an arbitrary vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$ onto this plane? How do we derive it?

In other words, I'm looking for an expression for the vector in $H$ that represents the orthogonal projection of some arbitrary vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$ onto $H$, in terms of $v$, $\theta$, $\theta_0$, and their dot products only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find the orthogonal projection of a vector onto an arbitrary plane?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3537320/how-do-i-find-the-orthogonal-projection-of-a-vector-onto-an-arbitrary-plane)

Comment: @AlanMuniz That's a question, not an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\theta_0 = 0$, then you just need to subtract away the orthogonal component (direction $\theta$) from $v$.

$$v -  \frac{v \cdot \theta}{\|\theta\|^2} \theta = (I - \frac{\theta \theta^\top}{\|\theta\|^2}) v$$

In general if $\theta_0 \ne 0$, shift everything by $v_0$ (where $v_0$ is any point on the plane $H$) first so that the plane touches the origin, perform the above projection, and then shift back.

$$(I - \frac{\theta \theta^\top}{\|\theta\|^2}) (v - v_0) + v_0$$

If you need an explicit choice of $v_0$, you can take $v_0 = - \frac{\theta_0}{\|\theta\|^2} \theta$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this. $\theta_0$ is a scalar. How do you subtract it from a vector $v$? Maybe my brain is burnt.

Comment: @TianJiang Sorry, I've corrected my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

use the fact that the vector $\vec H$ can always be expressed as the sum of two components:
$$
\vec H=\vec H_{||}+\vec H _{\bot}
$$
the first parallel to the plane (that is the projection that you need) and the second orthogonal to the plane, so parallel to your vector $\theta$.